# Can't access something with beautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having a bit of trouble accessing to a specific valut  in this web page (this is a french website for selling your old stuff).
I'm trying to get the number of visits for a specific item in there. Here is the link : http://www.kijiji.ca/v-velo-de-route/laval-rive-nord/velo-de-route-time/1280774723

Anyways here's my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent' : ua.chrome}
kjj_page = requests.get("http://www.kijiji.ca/v-velo-de-route/laval-rive-nord/velo-de-route-time/1280774723", headers=header)


soup = BeautifulSoup(kjj_page.content, 'lxml')       # This take two parameters, the file we want to parse and
                                                     # the parser

content = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : "ad-visits"})
print(content)
```

The problem is, on the website you can see that there is 83 visites (middle of the screen it's written "Visites" in french), but on my console I can't see that number... why? and how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

While opening that website, if you have Chrome Develper Tools (Or similar) open, you'll see that theres an `XHR` call to this address `http://www.kijiji.ca/j-vac-inc-get.json`.

If you pass the page ID as a `GET`parameter you'll get the number of visits.
Here is an example for that page:

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

URL = "http://www.kijiji.ca/v-velo-de-route/laval-rive-nord/velo-de-route-time/1280774723"
URL_ID = URL.split('/')[-1]

ua = UserAgent()
header = {'user-agent' : ua.chrome}
kjj_page = requests.get("http://www.kijiji.ca/j-vac-inc-get.json?adId=%s" % URL_ID, headers=header)

print (kjj_page.json()["numVisits"])
```

Which outputs the current number of visits:

> 85

Comment: Hey tanks a lot for your answer, but unfortunately, I almost don't understant what you're talking about. What' a XHR call? where does the adress you picked come from? Do you have a tutorial that can explain me all the stuff you're mentionning? Thanks a lot Pal!

Answer (score 0):

Try this selector:

```
content = soup.findAll("span", "ad-visits")
```

There are more examples on the [documentation page](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)